# capture/store when fields in database records have been changed/edited

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sybase-asa

I have a multi user database system which stores records with various fields e.g. text, date time etc.

Does anyone know of a way to capture when fields of a record have been changed/modified by a user. A bit like a audit history which displays all the events which have happened against the record.

I connect to database via tdatasource and TADQuery (fireDAC).

Thanks,

Comment: Do this on the DBMS side.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a solution where every important table has a number of triggers that fire when inserting, updating, deleting records. Those triggers save the old and the new state of the record to a corresponding "history" table.